# Java Generic Serializable, Iterable Stack

Tags: java, generics, serialization, stack

The following is the snippet of my program to serialize and deserialize a generic stack
**Deserialization Method**

```
public Stack<?> readAll(Path aPath){
    Stack<?> temp = new Stack<>();
    try(ObjectInputStream readStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(aPath)))) {
        temp = (Stack<?>) readStream.readObject();
    }catch(EOFException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("EOF");
    }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

**Serialization Method**

```
public void writeAll(Path aPath) {
    try(ObjectOutputStream writeStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(aPath)))) {
        writeStream.writeObject(this);
    }catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**How data is serialized and deserialized**

```
import java.nio.file.*;
public class StackTrial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = {"A","B","C","D","E"};
        Stack<String> stringStack = new Stack<>(); //Stack that will be Serialized
        Stack<String> readStack = new Stack<>(); //Stack in which data will be read
        Path aPath = Paths.get("C:/Documents and Settings/USER/Beginning Java 7/Stack.txt");//Path of file

        for(String name : names) { //pushing data in
            stringStack.push(name);
        }

        for(String a : stringStack) { //displaying content
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        stringStack.writeAll(aPath); //Serialize
        readStack = (Stack<String>) readStack.readAll(aPath);//Deserialize

        for(String a : readStack) { //Display the data read
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

*Question:* Is the return type of the readAll() method really doing anything to provide flexibility or it won't matter if I change it to `Stack<T>` 
My logic was that there maybe chances that data that was written to the file maybe of `Stack<Integer>` so while reading it back it might cause troubles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible for the compiler to check if what you read is a `Stack<Integer>`, a `Stack<String>`, or a `Stack<Whatever>`. So in the end, *you* have to know what is in the stack, and you have to decide the type of the stack. The rest is syntactic sugar.

If you leave it like that, and you know you're reading a `Stack<Integer>`, you'll have to write

```
Stack<Integer> stack = (Stack<Integer>) readAll(path);
```

If you write it as

```
public <T> Stack<T> readAll(Path aPath) {...}
```

the compiler can infer the type from the declaration of the variable, and you can thus write

```
Stack<Integer> stack = readAll(path);
```

But in the end, the result is the same. You'll get an exception when getting an Integer from the stack if it's not really a `Stack<Integer>`.

Comment: here: `public <T> Stack<T> readAll(Path aPath) {...}` the `<T>` following public isn't necessary is it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Else the method wouldn't be a generic method, and the compiler would search for a concrete class named T.

Comment: and in case of my method `public Stack<?> readAll(Path aPath)` I do not need a `<something>` as it is a wildcard right ? Only if it was `public Stack<T> readAll(Path aPath)` will I need a `<T>`

Comment: Ok I applied the changes to all the constructors and methods and things are now being flagged as errors

Comment: Oh. So you're implementing your own Stack class. I missed that. Why don't you use the standard collection classes? Anyway, I don't know how your Stack is implemented, and I don't know what the error is... But I suspect your class is already generic, so you don't need to parameterize the push method.

Comment: Yes , it is a user-defined class. so when do I need to put a `<T>` after `public static` or whatever. A thumb rule I mean.

Comment: readAll returns a new Stack, with a type that is potentially different from the type of the Stack on which you call the method. So it must be paameterized. BTW, readAll should be a static method, since it's not at all related to the instance on which it's called. OTOH, push() takes as argument an object which must have the generic type of the Stack, which is already declared at the class level.

Comment: well, since all is working well even without specifying `<T>` anywhere , I will prefer to skip it for now :)

Comment: referring back to `public <T> Stack<T> readAll(Path aPath) {...}` will the `<T>` not be inferred from the declaration of the stack ? Example : `Stack<String>` so T = String. For the method also T = String. Well, it would make sense if `readAll()` was static and then I would have to specify `<T>`

Comment: I initially supposed this method was not part of the Stack class, because I didn't understand you were not just using the standard Stack class, be rewriting your own (and also because such a method should not be an instance method of a Stack class anyway).

Comment: yeah , it should be static. Static methods need a `<T>` to specify they are generic . Confusion solved 0:)